# Have I burned out my HD motor?

Tags: voltage, amperage, converter

I accidentally cross connected my external HD and my computer power cables.
Only noticed it when my computer complained it was not charging.

MY HDD is no working but I have had problems with it before. So, I am wondering if I have burnt out the motor or maybe killed the power convertor of the HDD.

The power output of the computer cable is listed as 19V - 4.74A
The power output of the HDD cable is listed as 12V - 1.5A.

So, the big question is, which one is dead?
The transformer of the HDD seems to be a little warm. It never gets very warm. Does that mean it is working?

Is it something that a lab would be able to easily check without costing a fortune?

Comment: the external HD probably consits of a hard drive and a power supply and an interface board inside a case .... take the HD out of its case and plug it in inside a computer

Comment: yes, but external 12V passes through to the drive unaltered, 19V not good,

Answer (score 3):

The motor is probably still good, but the motor drive electronics are probably toast.

You're likely up for "repair or replace controller board" this will probably cost more than a new drive, but less than $1000.